# Finding total number of lattice points on a circle and one of the coordinate values

Tags: number-theory, analytic-geometry, integer-lattices

I was wondering if it was possible to quickly find the total amount of lattice points on a circle, given its equation (origin and radius), and I was also a bit confused on how to find a particular point. I don't really have an example, since I only heard of this since my friends younger brother asked us for help, and neither of us had seen this before. Are there standard equations for both finding a specific coordinate point and to find the total amount of points on the circle?

(I suppose to simply it/help my understanding ill just make up a random circle):

$(x-7)^2+(y-3)^2=20$

Comment: @WillJagy Finding the answers is easy using a tool like wolfram. I had already done this. I was wondering if there was a practical way to solve for those points.

Comment: given $D,$ for you $D = 20,$ find all solutions to $u^2 + v^2 = D,$ say with $0 \leq u \leq v.$ When $0 < u < v,$ you get eight points using the center $(A,B),$ out of $(A \pm u, B \pm v); (A \pm v, B \pm u).$ I should have provided 8 points. Note that most numbers $D$ are not the sum of two squares.

Comment: Would it be something like x^2+y^2 = 20.. Then find perfect squares that are >20, so 1, 4, 9, 16 ... (+/-2, +/-4) (+/-4, +/-2) then add 7 to the x and 3 to the y?

Comment: @WillJagy So what if the radius was instead sqr(21) instead of sqr(20)?

Comment: for $D=21,$ no lattice points.

Comment: @WillJagy So in order for it to have lattice points, the R must be the sum of perfect squares?

Comment: itself square or the sum of exactly two squares. I was calling it $D$

Comment: Oh alright that makes sense. Thanks!